# Querying collection with array of ObjectId elements

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

[Dialog schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktZeT.png)

This query returns empty array, but users is an array of ObjectId elements and userDialogs.messages is an array of ObjectId elements aswell

```
DialogModel.find({users: {$in: userDialogs.messages}}, {})
```

Comment: could you provide the DialogModel schema, and also a snapshot from the userDialogs.messages?

Comment: @Mohammed Yousry, done

Comment: could you provide the schema code better, rather than an image, the users array is not clear in the image, also this object userDialogs, could you provide it too?

Comment: @ Mohammed Yousry, I solved my problem, I was searching for wrong fields